# minify javascript with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, minify

I want to minimize javascript in C#. Take for example this javascript I found at: http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/

```
(function (skillet, $, undefined) {
        //Private Property
        var isHot = true;

        //Public Property
        skillet.ingredient = "Bacon Strips";

        //Public Method
        skillet.fry = function () {
            var oliveOil;

            addItem("\t\n Butter \n\t");
            addItem(oliveOil);
            console.log("Frying " + skillet.ingredient);
        };

        //Private Method
        function addItem(item) {
            if (item !== undefined) {
                console.log("Adding " + $.trim(item));
            }
        }
    } (window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery));
```

Is there any simple C# method I could write to minimize this to one line, removing whitespace etc? I want to right something custom to do this rather than using Minifer or Yahoo.

Comment: @amateur: Why roll your own when there are so many existing solutions that work well?

Comment: I don't want to use a 3rd party solution but just want something simple and basic.

Comment: @amateur: Unless you have a contractual obligation **not** to use third-party libraries I don't see why you'd want to develop something that already exists, is tested, has active community support, etc etc.

Comment: @amateur: unless this is your homework...

Comment: @amateur, it is considered polite to accept answers to your questions. To a large extent, you have neglected to do so. You may want to go back and accept answers to your previous questions. This may motivate further help from other StackOverflow users.

Comment: @Rodrigo, I do when I get an acceptable answer to questions. Thanks for your concern...

Comment: And my answer is not acceptable? I really like to read your comments on my answer to learn why you don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To straight up answer your question yes there is a pretty simple method you can write.  Just look at the string one character at a time and see if it's something you want to keep or not.  Once you've got that working start a look ahead.  By this I mean your going to need to look forward say when you get a " till you get another " and not do anything to the text between the two quotes, do the same thing with comments and what not and your good to go.

There are lots of open source things out there where you can look at the code to find this.
http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html (c++ but concept should be the same)
http://blog.andrewreitz.com/2011/07/web-minifier-c.html
to name a few

Answer (score 6):

[Douglas Crockford's JSMin.cs](https://github.com/rhapsodyn/jsmin-cs/blob/master/jsmin.cs)

Don't reinvent the wheel, please.

Comment: Care to paste the contents of that c# file since the link is broken now ?

Comment: Just updated the link, it only took me a single Google search